# How to convert from Large RasterLayer to Formal RasterLayer class in R?

Tags: raster, r

I'm a bit confused about types here. While I'm loading a image:

```
tif = raster(paste0(path))
```

I get some "Formal Class RasterLayer" object. But while I change it's matrix of values, for example:

```
idx <- values(tif) != 200
  values(tif)[idx] <- 255
```

if becomes "Large RasterLayer" object. And indeed it's large, for file of about 100Mpx it's over 270mb, while that first is about 10mb in memory.

How can I convert this new one into the "Formal" class to save memory?

I tried: `tif1 = raster(tif)` but object missing coordinates. `as.raster(tif)` returns raster chr variable.

**EDIT**

Found a workaround:

```
writeRaster(tif, "tif.tif")
tif = raster("tif.tif")
```

It takes much memory for process but at last its freed. Wish to find something faster without saving to disk.

Comment: Can you explain where you get those sizes from? I have a 1200x942 =~ 1Mpx file and the source tif is 63k bytes long and the R object is 16k bytes big according to `object.size(tif)`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake -> 100Mpx, not 1Mpx. I read it from RStudio Global Env. view and it's quite what is memory showing independently.